# Installing PYTHON3.8 and PyQt5 to the DOCKER CONTAINER with using DOCKERFILE

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, dockerfile, arm64

I have a project that contains a lot of library (requirements.txt) and I want to create a dockerfıle when I build this docker file in docker container I need python3.8 and ın python3.8 I need PyQt5 library.

When I create a simple dockerfile just consist of

---

### FROM ubuntu:22.04

### COPY . /app

---

The problem that I facing is when I try:

---

### apt-get install python3-pyqt5

---

PyQt5 install python3.11 or python 3.10 and install PyQt5 in this directory.

But my project only run in python3.8 what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&\
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y python3.8 &&\
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 10 &&\
    update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 &&\
    apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: also can you check out my new Dockerfile maybe I can go with this dockerfile because I have to use linux/arm64 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded the file Dockerfile like this because I need the architecture of the container arm64

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.8.10-slim
COPY . /app
ENV LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1unam
```

but now I cant install pyqt5 library using

```
apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

code in the container. Container give's me the error that is

- Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [22 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mwq0m6h0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mwq0m6h0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mwq0m6h0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "/tmp/pip-install-4lcxi4is/pyqt5_d62bb4d4ab2a424eae5f92329bee727e/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mwq0m6h0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mwq0m6h0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mwq0m6h0/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

---